# How to catch exception thrown from a custom class into activity?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Java/Android, first timer

I have developed a class which updates Firebase DB using SetValue() and throws exception if there is error from OnComplete (DatabaseReference.CompletionListener).

In my activity I have encased call to method (in above said class) in Try-Catch.

Problem is as following :

1. I am unable to trap error so that I can show error in Toast.
2. App crashes when in debug mode.
3. I can see error in console and this error is reason for crash.
4. When not in debug mode, app executes immediate following statement in activity code which displays toast "Data saved successfully."

Please note I have deliberately altered firebase security so that user cannot write.

Custom class code :

```
package com.mypack.fdbmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class FbDbManager {
    FirebaseDatabase MyDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference MyRef = MyDb.getReference("Users/User_01");
    DatabaseReference MyDataRef = MyRef.child("Message");
    Context MyContext;

    public FbDbManager(Context context) {
        MyContext = context;
    }

    public void UpdateUser(String valueToUpdate) {
    MyDataRef.setValue(valueToUpdate, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
            if (databaseError != null) {
                throw databaseError.toException();
            } else {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is my Activity code :

```
package com.mypack.fdbmanager;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FbDbManager myDbRef;
    Button myButton_Send;
    EditText myEdiText_Message;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myDbRef = new FbDbManager(this);
        myButton_Send = findViewById(R.id.button_Send);
        myEdiText_Message = findViewById(R.id.editText_Message);

        myButton_Send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                UpdateUser();
            }
        });
    }

    private void UpdateUser() {
        try {
              myDbRef.UpdateUser(myEdiText_Message.getText().toString().trim());
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data saved successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
 }
 }
```

**Here is trace :**

> V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1 E/FA: Discarding data.
>   Failed to send event to service D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent:
>   0xa9c06440: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9c035f0) D/EGL_emulation:
>   eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9c06440: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9c035f0)
>   ***W/RepoOperation: setValue at /Users/User_01/Message failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied*** I/zygote: Do partial code cache
>   collection, code=61KB, data=49KB I/zygote: After code cache
>   collection, code=61KB, data=49KB I/zygote: Increasing code cache
>   capacity to 256KB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're assuming that your CompletionListener executes synchronously with the call to UpdateUser.  That's not the way it works.  The callback in invoked asynchronously - calls to `MyDataRef.setValue()` always return immediately, and the callback is invoked an unknown amount of time later.  Meanwhile, your UpdateUser methods are returning without any knowledge of a problem, because the exception cannot "escape" the function.  Run this in a debugger with breakpoints at the top of each method, or put log statements between every line, to get a feel for how it works.

To fix this, tour database helper method should be accepting and invoking async callbacks.  They should not be expecting to block on the results of a query.  You have some pretty significant restructuring to do.

Comment: Thank you for clearing my fundamentals. You cleared the cloud in my head. :) Also thanks to all for their time and effort.

Comment: Doug, Do you have link to share which will help me restructuring my database helper? It will help me move forward faster. Thank you in advance,

Comment: Sorry, I don't see helpers like this very often.  Your helper could simply take a CompletionListener as an argument just like setValue(), or some abstraction of that listener that simply calls through.  Or it could return the Task that setValue() returns, and the caller can listen to that.

Comment: Thanks a ton Doug for your prompt response, appreciate immensely.

Answer (score 0):

Permission denied is the error which comes up when the user is not authorized. Change your database rules:

This rule will allow database read and write if user is authorized or logged in

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

This rule will allow database read and write without checking if the user is authorized.

```
{
   "rules": {
     ".read": "true",
     ".write": "true"
   }
 }
```

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply. I have deliberately altered .write: "false". I want to throw error "Permission Denied" back to calling method so that i can show same in toast to user. I am unable to do so. :(

Comment: No my problem is not solved. I want to let user know that permission is denied.